# passing string paramater using p:commandButton

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I want send to two parameters using notificationUpdate function. I am able to pass p.email successfully but when I am trying to send status as a string,its getting passed as null.

```
<p:commandLink value="Views"
                                    action="#{statusBean.update(p.statusId)}" ajax="true"
                                    style="text-decoration:none;color:white;" update=":statusBlock" >
                                    <f:actionListener binding="#{notificationBean.notificationUpdate(p.email,status)}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: Please add context to your question. `status` is of what type? From what part of the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are meaning that you want to send the "status" String as a value, than try to send it as following:

```
<f:actionListener binding="#{notificationBean.notificationUpdate(p.email,'status')}" />
```